# QT: Clearing a QTableWidget in order to display new items

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I'm creating a program that displays a list of customers to a QTableWidget.  The table will not out put until one of the buttons are clicked.  Each button will output the correct items, however, for example, when i click "Key Customers" then "Show All" table will not change/output the new items to the table.

--

I want the table to clear its items then re-display new items on the same table widget.

--

I had this working before but didnt save the changes on the repo.

[This is how the window is displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE7Uh.png)

slot code:

```
///
/// \brief AdminWindow::on_showAll_Button_clicked
/// Displays a QTableWidget populated by all items in the customer list
///

void AdminWindow::on_showAll_Button_clicked()
{
QStringList header;
Customer* ptr=NULL;     /// \brief points to the current obj being output
int row=0;              /// \brief current row
int col=0;              /// \brief current col

ptr=CList.list.returnObj();

ui->tableWidget->reset();

header << "Name" << "Street Address" << "City Address" << "Rating" <<
          "Priority";
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header);

while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(row+1);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(col);

    col=0;
    QTableWidgetItem* newName = new QTableWidgetItem
            (ptr->getName());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newName);

    col=1;
    QTableWidgetItem* newStrtAd = new QTableWidgetItem
            (ptr->getStreetAd());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newStrtAd);

    col=2;
    QTableWidgetItem* newCtyAd = new QTableWidgetItem
            (ptr->getCityAd());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newCtyAd);

    col=3;
    QTableWidgetItem* newRate = new QTableWidgetItem
            (ptr->getRating());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newRate);

    col=4;
    QTableWidgetItem* newKey = new QTableWidgetItem
            (ptr->getKeyCust());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newKey);

    CList.list.getNext();
    ptr=CList.list.returnObj();
    row++;
    col++;
}
}

///
/// \brief AdminWindow::on_KeyButton_clicked
/// Displays a QTableWidget populated by the customer list and filtered
///     to display Key Customers
///

void AdminWindow::on_KeyButton_clicked()
{
QStringList header;
Customer* ptr=NULL;     /// \brief points to the current obj being output
int row=0;              /// \brief current row
int col=0;              /// \brief current col

ptr=CList.list.returnObj();

ui->tableWidget->reset();

header << "Name" << "Street Address" << "City Address" << "Rating" <<
          "Priority";
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header);

while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    if(ptr->getKeyCust()=="key")
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(row+1);
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(col);

        col=0;
        QTableWidgetItem* newName = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getName());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newName);

        col=1;
        QTableWidgetItem* newStrtAd = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getStreetAd());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newStrtAd);

        col=2;
        QTableWidgetItem* newCtyAd = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getCityAd());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newCtyAd);

        col=3;
        QTableWidgetItem* newRate = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getRating());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newRate);

        col=4;
        QTableWidgetItem* newKey = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getKeyCust());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newKey);

        CList.list.getNext();
        ptr=CList.list.returnObj();
        row++;
        col++;
    }else
    {
        CList.list.getNext();
        ptr=CList.list.returnObj();
    }
}
}

///
/// \brief AdminWindow::on_NonKeyButton_clicked -
/// Displays a QTableWidget populated by the customer list and filtered
///     to display only Non-Key customers
///
void AdminWindow::on_NonKeyButton_clicked()
{
QStringList header;
Customer* ptr=NULL;     /// \brief points to the current obj being output
int row=0;              /// \brief current row
int col=0;              /// \brief current col

ptr=CList.list.returnObj();

ui->tableWidget->reset();

header << "Name" << "Street Address" << "City Address" << "Rating" <<
          "Priority";
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header);

while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    if(ptr->getKeyCust()!="key")
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(row+1);
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(col);

        col=0;
        QTableWidgetItem* newName = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getName());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newName);

        col=1;
        QTableWidgetItem* newStrtAd = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getStreetAd());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newStrtAd);

        col=2;
        QTableWidgetItem* newCtyAd = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getCityAd());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newCtyAd);

        col=3;
        QTableWidgetItem* newRate = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getRating());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newRate);

        col=4;
        QTableWidgetItem* newKey = new QTableWidgetItem
                (ptr->getKeyCust());
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row-1, col, newKey);

        CList.list.getNext();
        ptr=CList.list.returnObj();
        row++;
        col++;
    }else
    {
        CList.list.getNext();
        ptr=CList.list.returnObj();
    }
}
}
```

I've tried all the ui->tableWidget->clear..() and ui->tableWidget->reset() methods to no avail.  Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: For 'dynamic' tables I've found the full model view stuff ('QAbstractItemModel' and a 'QTableView') much easier to work with. It also has the advantage that if you're wanting to show subsets of your data you can use a 'QSortFilterProxyModel' to do the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're looking for `tableWidget->setRowCount(0)`. This function clear the table, but not the header labels. I'm using it and it works better than `clear` and `reset` methods.

Comment: I've tried this before and just tried it once more.  The TableWidget is cleared, however it will not repopulate.